# How to make circle with colored halves?

Tags: symbols, color

In my math equations, I'd like to use a circle symbol which has the top and bottom half colored at a specific color. Ideally with a separating line at the diameter. The symbol should also work if I use it as a superscript in math mode.

So something like
[image]

What would be an approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with TikZ:

- The size adapts to the current math style. The example uses the size of letter `A`.
- The line width decreases with smaller line styles.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\twohalfcircle}[2]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathord{% change accordingly to the symbol type
      \mathpalette{\@twohalfcircle{#1}{#2}}{}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newdimen\@twohalfcircle@dimen
\newdimen\@twohalfcircle@linewidth
\newdimen\@twohalfcircle@radius
\newcommand*{\@twohalfcircle}[4]{%
  % #1: bottom color
  % #2: top color
  % #3: math style
  % #4: unused
  \sbox0{$#3A$}%
  \@twohalfcircle@dimen=\ht0 %
  \@twohalfcircle@linewidth=.06\@twohalfcircle@dimen
  \pgfmathsetlength\@twohalfcircle@radius{%
    .5\@twohalfcircle@dimen
    - .5\@twohalfcircle@linewidth
  }%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    baseline=-.5\@twohalfcircle@dimen,
    x=\@twohalfcircle@dimen,
    y=\@twohalfcircle@dimen,
    radius=\@twohalfcircle@radius,
    line width=\@twohalfcircle@linewidth,
  ]
    \filldraw[fill={#1}] circle[];
    \filldraw[fill={#2}]
      (-\@twohalfcircle@radius, 0)
      arc(180:360:\@twohalfcircle@radius)
      -- cycle
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \twohalfcircle{green}{yellow}
  ^{\twohalfcircle{blue}{red}^{\twohalfcircle{orange}{cyan}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nice. It would be nicer if the line width change according to radius.

Comment: @Sigur, yes, I was already preparing it, see the updated answer.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty nice. I didn't guess how much little tuning there is.